# Participle adjective following preposition

Tags: grammar

In the example 
"The matter be treated as closed"
Here,  "as "is used as preposition(not conjunction) followed by participle adjective. What does "closed"modify here since normally the Noun follows preposition.

Comment: It's probably best to see 'They treated the matter as [being] closed' as a paraphrase of 'They consigned the matter to the 'closed' category'. Even in 'The matter is closed', the participial adjective 'closed' (in the usual reading) is arguably a transferred usage.  Looking for modified nouns is not always helpful; how are the nouns 'modified' in 'former president', 'fake diamond', 'proud day', mere youth'? These 'non-semantically-predicative' adjectives are really describing contexts surrounding the referents.

Comment: OP's question lacks clarity. It sounds like an imperative passivized. Treat the matter as closed. AV;  (Let) the matter be treated as closed. PV.

Comment: It's not a modifier. "Closed" is an adjective functioning as complement of "as". More specifically, it is a 'predicative oblique', with "matter" as predicand (what it refers to).  The _as_ phrase is then a 'marked predicative complement'.

Comment: Thanks again Bill. If i understood  you correctly, 'as'is functioning like a preposition here. Thanks

Comment: Yes, certainly "as" **is** a preposition here.